# Spring MVC 3.2 Rest JSON data conversion

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to send List of data as JSON from my Spring Controller but it is throwing "Could not find acceptable representation". below are the code snippets of the various parts of my application.

pom.xml

```
<hibernate.version>4.1.4.Final</hibernate.version>
<spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.data.version>1.3.2.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
<jackson.version>1.9.12</jackson.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- 
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
 -->
```

WebConfig. I tried all possible ways mentioned in various blogs and stackoverflow. I tried the ones which is commented as well.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.test.testing")
//@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.testing.config.dao")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }




    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
        .useJaf(false)
        .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
        .mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .mediaType("plain", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(
            ContentNegotiationManager manager) {

        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

        InternalResourceViewResolver r1 = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        r1.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        r1.setSuffix(".jsp");
        r1.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolvers.add(r1);

        JsonViewResolver r2 = new JsonViewResolver();

        resolvers.add(r2);

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
        return resolver;

    }



    /**
     * View resolver for returning JSON in a view-based system. Always returns a
     * {@link MappingJacksonJsonView}.
     */
    public class JsonViewResolver implements ViewResolver {
        @Override
        public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale)
                throws Exception {
            MappingJacksonJsonView view = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
            view.setPrettyPrint(true);
            return view;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
        exceptionResolver.setDefaultErrorView("uncaughtException");
        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.put(".DataAccessException", "dataAccessFailure");
        mappings.put(".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException", "resourceNotFound");
        mappings.put(".TypeMismatchException", "resourceNotFound");
        mappings.put(".MissingServletRequestParameterException", "resourceNotFound");
        exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings );
        return exceptionResolver;
    }




    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter#configureMessageConverters(java.util.List)
     */

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(new org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter());
        //converters.add(new org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        //converters.add(new org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        /*
        org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(new com.test.testing.objectmapper.MasterDataObjectMapper());

        converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);

        */

        org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(new MasterDataObjectMapper());
        converters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);


    }


}
```

Controller. Sysout of the controller method

getMasterTypeData Master Data Type List :[MasterType [id=1, value=UAT/QA], MasterType [id=4, value=Development], MasterType [id=2, value=Model], MasterType [id=3, value=Production]]

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdata/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<MasterType> getMasterTypeData(@PathVariable String type) {

        MASTERDATATYPE master = MASTERDATATYPE.getMasterDataType(type); 
        List<MasterType> masterdatTypeList = new ArrayList<MasterType>();
        System.out.println("getMasterTypeData Input :"+type+",MASTERDATATYPE :"+master);

        // some logics to populate masterdatTypeList 

        System.out.println("getMasterTypeData Master Data Type List :"+masterdatTypeList);
        return masterdatTypeList;
    }
```

and finally MasterType class which I would like to send back to browser ad JSON object

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class MasterType implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String value;

public MasterType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MasterType(EnvironmentType environmentType){
    this.id = environmentType.getId();
    this.value = environmentType.getEnvName();
}

public MasterType(OperatingSystemType operatingSystemType){
    this.id = operatingSystemType.getId();
    this.value = operatingSystemType.getOsName();
}

public MasterType(ServerStorageBillableType serverStorageBillableType){
    this.id = serverStorageBillableType.getId();
    this.value = serverStorageBillableType.getStorageBillableTypeDesc();
}

public MasterType(ServerStorageStatusType serverStorageStatusType){
    this.id = serverStorageStatusType.getId();
    this.value = serverStorageStatusType.getStorageStatusName();
}

public MasterType(ServerStorageType serverStorageType){
    this.id = serverStorageType.getId();
    this.value = serverStorageType.getStorageTypeName();
}

public MasterType(ServerComponentType serverComponentType){
    this.id = serverComponentType.getId();
    this.value = serverComponentType.getComponentName();
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
//@JsonProperty
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the value
 */
//@JsonProperty
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
/**
 * @param value the value to set
 */
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
    return result;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    MasterType other = (MasterType) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (value == null) {
        if (other.value != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
        return false;
    return true;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("MasterType [id=").append(id).append(", value=")
            .append(value).append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your request headers are set and have "Accept  application/json" , you can use firebug to inspect the request headers.

Comment: Yes its there, it's reaching the method but somehow while returning the list it's failing

Comment: Will you be able to check out show-case project and figure out . I tried your MasterType class, I was able to return a list of types. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase